# Are there use-cases for new types of punctuation outside of the standard set?

Tags: punctuation, clauses, technical

Do you think we would benefit from additional punctuation (or 'notation', in a broade sense)  in prose? Can you give any examples of possible use cases for a new piece of notation/punctuation. I am most interested in the normative question (and have now changed the title of the questions reflect that), but am secondarily interested in the sociological/historical question:

Has there been any recently proposed new types of punctuation that have gained any support, say within the past fifty years? If so can you give some examples? If not, why do you think this has not happened. (a sociological question.)

Apologies in advance if there are strict rules on here about questions being restricted to be *questions* only, not statements, but I'd like to preemptively respond to some people that might dismiss the question because they think what we have is good enough and not worth messing with.

I can certainly see the argument for keeping punctuation standardized to a small set of symbols and uses, but it seems to me that there are certain cases where the currently standard set of punctuation is not optimal for communication speed and clarity. I don't have an example ready, but I think some such cases occur when there are several different clauses in a sentence with complex structure, including clauses that are 'interpolation' clauses if I'm using that term correctly. Some writers would advise to simply break up such complex sentences, and in many cases I would agree. But I think there are some cases where, in order to communicate something, multiple concepts need to be combined into the same sentence since thinking of each concept separately is not adequate-- one needs to dedicate their working memory to thinking of all of these concept at the same time in order to understand the composite idea. (something like that...).

I also think that in some cases the comma is asked to perform too many different roles and it is not clear, at least not until reading the entire sentence and backtracking, which roles which commas are playing. I understand that dashes, parentheses, and brackets can also be used to play some the same and different roles and so can disambiguate, so it's possible that I just need to learn how to use these better, but I'm still not totally convinced that will be good enough for a lot of important cases. 
As I said, I don't have examples ready right now (and I'm by no means an expert in punctuation grammar or writing), but if the community doubts that there is possible benefit from new punctuation/notation, let me know and I may attempt to construct some examples.

Looking forward to your answers, thanks!

### Edit: an example (since no one else gave one)

Sometimes a sentence has a long noun phrase and you want to demarcate where it starts and ends so that the reader can understand the grammatical structure of the (long) sentence before they finish reading it (so they don't have to reread once they understand). I'm not sure how to do that with standard punctuation? In the example below (taking from an old essay from college), I try using brackets but I don't think that's standard. In this case, it would probably be better just to break up the sentence, but I hope it illustrates that this sort of noun-phrase demarcation can be useful.

> A truth theory that could be known on the basis of [observation of
>   what is held true in what circumstances in conjunction with
>   understanding of what kinds of things people would likely have reason
>   to want to communicate or say in what circumstances] would suffice for
>   interpretation of a language.

(Sorry, the topic of the sentence is pretty obscure. I just remembered this sentence from a while ago and copied it and pasted here. One could certainly construct an example with a more mundane topic that illustrates the same point.)

Nested delimiters might become reasonable if we have color pair-matching.

(Finally, before asking this question, I did a quick google search and came upon this [doctoral dissertation](https://dc.uwm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1470&context=etd) on the subject of punctuation. I was somewhat disappointed that it did not discuss the topic of this question further, being a broader study of punctuation that does not appear to get 'super' in-depth on any one topic, but may be a useful reference, or are there much better places to read about this?)

Comment: This just isn't how natural language (and in particular, ***English***) works. There is no "Language Committee" deciding what if any changes to introduce into English. In France the [*Académie française*](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/8820304/Frances-Academie-francaise-battles-to-protect-language-from-English.html) (and politicians & such) still try to exercise control - but they fought tooth and nail against ***le weekend***, and the French ***people*** took absolutely no notice of them anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point, I don't mean to restrict the question to new punctionuation being introduced by a central authority, I'm open to it diffusing naturally throughout the population as people see others use it and like it, I will try to update the question accordingly.

Comment: I sometimes "pair match" my smiley close-bracket (like this! :), but I'm not holding my breath waiting to see that device adopted more generally. It doesn't actually work ***at all*** on my smartphone, which insists on replacing the **colon + close-bracket** symbol pair with a single image. But for a detectable "trend" in modern orthography, I'd say there's definitely a long-term shift towards ***shorter sentences, less punctuation*** (which no doubt Hemingway would be pleased to see! :)

Comment: Now that popular media has more capability than the quill, perhaps the emoji can be considered as punctuation – at least as various forms of the exclamation mark!

Comment: The only one I know of is the [interrobang](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interrobang)

Comment: After seeing a few of these comments, I have decided I am more interested in the 'normative question' of whether we should adopt new kinds of punctuation rather than whether we have. I have changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: I! ,really, -do- think> punctuation, needs, some. new features,

Comment: Note that the "central authority" here is the standard English keyboard, and, to a lesser degree, standard computer character sets.

Comment: You mentioned attempting to construct some examples, but if there really is a need for new types of punctuation shouldn't there be some examples readily to hand? If not, the use cases must be pretty obscure, no?

Comment: @nnnnnn I put one now.